# iTunes not installing .ipa file

Tags: iphone, itunes, ad-hoc-distribution

I'm trying to install an app I coded on an iPhone using Ad Hoc distribution. I dragged the .mobileprovision file (associated with my iPhone UDID) to the "Apps" item under "Library" in iTunes (Windows). When I do so, nothing happens, no confirmation messages or errors. (Is there a way to know which .mobileprovision files are installed in iTunes?)

When I double-click the .ipa file, again nothing happens. But what is worse is that the app doesn't even appear under "Apps" in iTunes. I also tried to drag-and-drop it under "Apps" in iTunes but again nothing happens.

Did anyone else face this problem before?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Edit: I tried on another computer running Windows and the same version of iTunes and it works! Still not able to make it work on my computer though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow the bellow steps

1). **Right Click on .app file which is underneath of Product Folder in xcode** Left side and choose **Show in Finder**

2). **Compress** this **app file with your provisioning** (must contain your UDID)

3). Upload this Zip file to [http://www.diawi.com](http://www.diawi.com/) website.

4) you will get one link there.

5). Open it in Safari of your iOS device.

6). Install Provisioning first then install application file.

It's best way for Ad-Hoc Distribution and help you to send built.

Hope it helps you !!!

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not looking for an alternative. I know the official way to do it has to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommand to use the [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1466?viewlocale=en_US). You can manage the provisioning file, the apps, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. App would not load--no error messages, just falls off the cliff. After pulling all my hair out, I discovered that the iPad I was using had not been authorized by the app-store. Even though I was trying to load an ipa file from my system, iTunes didn't seem to know the difference.